# Apache AGE - Creating Functions With Multiple Parameters

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

I was looking inside the `create_vlabel` function and noted that to get the `graph_name` and  `label_name` it is used `graph_name = PG_GETARG_NAME(0)` and `label_name = PG_GETARG_NAME(1)`. Since these two variables are also passed as parameters, I was thinking that, if I wanted to add one more parameter to this function, then I would need to use `PG_GETARG_NAME(2)` to get this parameter and use it in the function's logic. Is my assumption correct or do I need to do more tweaks to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, but you also need to change the function signature in the "age--1.2.0.sql" file, updating the arguments:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ag_catalog.create_vlabel(graph_name name, label_name name, type new_argument)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE c
AS 'MODULE_PATHNAME';
```

Note that all arguments come as a "Datum" struct, and `PG_GETARG_NAME` automatically converts it to a "Name" struct. If you need an argument as int32, for example, you should use `PG_GETARG_INT32(index_of_the_argument)`, for strings, `PG_GETARG_CSTRING(n)`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The answers given by Fahad Zaheer and Marco Souza are correct, but you can also create a Variadic function, with which you could have n number of arguments but one drawback is that you would have to check the type yourself. You can find more information [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/variadic-functions-in-c/amp/). You can also check many Apache Age functions made this way e.g agtype_to_int2.